# Unable to auto start service (SoftEther VPN) on Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: server, vpn, services, autostart

I am running Ubuntu Server 22.04 in a VMware Workstation VM (Host OS is Windows 11 Pro).

I find that I have to manually start the Softether VPN by running "/etc/init.d/vpnserver start". So at least it installed correctly

I tried running "update-rc.d vpnserver defaults" to make it autostart after login to no avail.

I tried this guide,: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/softether-is-not-starting-after-reboot

However, the problem is when I go enable the service with
`sudo systemctl enable vpnserver.service`, it gives me an error:

```
update-rc.d: error: vpnserver Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting
```

I tried 3 variations:

#1
"sudo nano /etc/init.d/vpnserver"

```
> #!/bin/sh
> # chkconfig: 2345 99 01
> # description: SoftEther VPN Server sleep 10 DAEMON=/usr/local/vpnserver/vpnserver LOCK=/var/lock/subsys/vpnserver
> test -x $DAEMON || exit 0 case "$1" in start) $DAEMON start touch
> $LOCK ;; stop) $DAEMON stop rm $LOCK ;; restart) $DAEMON stop sleep 3
> $DAEMON start ;;
> *) echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}" exit 1 esac /etc/init.d/vpnserver start exit 0
```

#2 (with code below)
"sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/vpnserver.service"

-- and--

#3 (with code below)
"nano /lib/systemd/system/vpnserver.service"

```
Description=SoftEther VPN Server
After=network.target


[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/vpnserver/vpnserver start
ExecStop=/usr/local/vpnserver/vpnserver stop


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I followed the same guide and had the same issue, but was able to get the service to start on boot by adding a ### BEGIN INIT INFO block to the vpnserver file in init.d and then re-running the systemctl enable command.

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/vpnserver
```

Added the ### BEGIN INIT INFO / ### END INIT INFO block to the top of the file, right after the #!/bin/sh line. The rest of the file is the same as it was in the guide.

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:             vpnserver
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:        2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description:    SoftEtherVPNServer
### END INIT INFO

# chkconfig: 2345 99 01
# description: SoftEther VPN Server
DAEMON=/usr/local/vpnserver/vpnserver
LOCK=/var/lock/subsys/vpnserver
test -x $DAEMON || exit 0
case "$1" in
start)
$DAEMON start
touch $LOCK
;;
stop)
$DAEMON stop
rm $LOCK
;;
restart)
$DAEMON stop
sleep 3
$DAEMON start
;;
*)
echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

Then run the enable command again,

```
systemctl enable vpnserver.service
```

after which the VPN service starts automatically when I reboot the server.